# Why has speech-to-text stopped working on my phone?

Tags: htc-desire-z, voice-recognition

I have an HTC Desire Z with Android 2.2. For some reason my speech to text convertor has stopped working. Everytime the soft keyboard opens up and I press on the small mike button, it says audio problem and closes. Up until yesterday, the phone was fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try clearing the data for it.  Do so via `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and finding **Voice Search** (or the relevant app if you're using another) under the **All** tab.

Comment: tried this but not working, it is still saying "there is a problem with the audio"

Comment: Hmm.  Have you tried rebooting the phone?

Comment: yup tried it,some application had locked the microphone. anyways, how do i change the microphone settings without rebooting the phone. i searched in the settings but i could not find microphone in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i fixed it by uninstalling the updates for google keyboard and somehow everything was fixed

Comment: Google Keyboard wasn't a standalone app 4 years ago when this question was posted. That couldn't possibly be the solution to this user's problem. But presumably they've replaced their phone at least once since then, making this irrelevant.

Comment: I'd say this is quite useful to people finding this questions *now* who are having the problem in the title, without the same now-ancient device and software.